# How to calculate $ \mathbb{Z}[x] /\langle2x-1\rangle $?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I don't understand very well the quotient, so, I do not know if calculate is the correct word, but I need to simplify the expression $$ \mathbb{Z}[x] /\langle2x-1\rangle  $$

Comment: What would you like to simplify it to? And what are your thoughts? What have you tried?

Comment: Shouldn't you have asked [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3218279/what-is-the-meaning-of-2x-1-in-ring-theory) then first?

Answer (score 3):

I believe by "simplification" you mean "to find an algebraic structure isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(2x-1)$ but of a simpler form".

First we want to know what the elements in $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(2x-1)$ look like. For any $f(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$, we divide it by $2x-1$ to obtain
$$f(x)=q(x)(2x-1)+r(x)$$
with $\deg r(x)<\deg(2x-1)=1$, then $r(x)=c$ is a constant, and $f(x)\mod (2x-1)$ is
$$\overline{f(x)}=\overline{q(x)(2x-1)+c}=\overline{q(x)(2x-1)}+\bar c=\bar c$$
because $\overline{2x-1}=\bar0$. This means any element in $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(2x-1)$ can be represented by a number in $\mathbb{Z}$. Conversely, it is easy to see two different numbers in $\mathbb{Z}$ do not represent the same equivalence class in $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(2x-1)$. So one should make a guess that
$$\mathbb{Z}[x]/(2x-1)\cong\mathbb{Z}$$
and this is indeed the answer. It remains to verify this isomorphism, i.e., find such an isomorphism. Can you take it from here?

$\textbf{Hint}:$ My argument above gives a well-defined mapping
$$\mathbb{Z}[x]\to\mathbb{Z}$$
$$f(x)\mapsto c$$
Verify this is a homomorphism, and then an epimorphism, and find its kernel.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Consider the ring homomorphism from the ring of polynomials to the dyadic fractions:
\begin{align}
f:\mathbf Z[x]&\longrightarrow \mathbf Z_2\\
x&\longmapsto \tfrac12
\end{align}
Show that it is surjective and that its kernel is generated by $2x-1$.

Comment: the integers that their half is 0, so is (0) ?

Comment: No,  the kernel consists of polynomials.

Comment: But if you sent all the polinomials $x$ to $1/2$ so the kernel is empty set.

Comment: You misundertood my hint: a homomorphism from a polynomial ring in any $\mathbf Z$-algebra is determined by the image of the indeterminate $x$. So if $x$ maps to $\frac 12$, $x^2$ maps to $\frac14$, and more generally, a polynomial $p(x)$ maps to $p(\frac12)$.

Comment: I see. Thank you.